# Laundry drain smells like sewer after washing clothes

Tags: plumbing, vent, sewer, laundry, p-trap

I have an in-wall laundry drain - pictured below.

Since we moved in it had a significant clog which I unclogged with a combination of wet-vac sucking on the drain and snaking the vent pipe. Finally we got it to drain without flooding but now there's an awful sewer smell after doing laundry. Before unclogging, while it did flood fairly quickly, there was no sewer smell

So my questions are:

- How can I determine if the sewer smell is from a lack of p-trap in the wall (ideally without removing drywall)?
- Could the sewer smell come from another clog?
- Whether or not there is a p-trap in the wall, could I just put a p-trap outside of the wall attached to the plate to solve the smell?

[image: in wall drain]

Comment: Take a picture with flash down the pipe and you might be able to see whether there is a water surface (indicating presence of a trap) or a dry pipe. (There could be a bend before a trap, though.)

Comment: have someone flush a toilet in the house ... listen at the laundry drain ... if you hear the rush of water, then there is an open path to the sewer

Comment: @KevinReid this is the best picture I could take: https://i.imgur.com/vCKVb9j.jpeg pretty inclusive I'd say?

Comment: @jsotola flushed both toilets in the house and while I could hear the water under the house filling the toilets, no sound due to the flushing. the water heater is in the same room as the laundry

Comment: drain the washing machine into a bucket and smell it

Comment: look for a floor drain ... the vacuum cleaner may have sucked water out of the trap in the floor ... it may be refilled by running water at a tub ( thin tube from tap to drain)

Comment: there may be a sewer stub that was only covered by duct tape and the vacuum damaged the tape

Comment: wrap tape around the drain hose so that it fits tightly into the pipe

Comment: @jsotola no floor drain sadly. I can try to affix the drain hose tightly into the pipe, but the gases would just exhaust through the washer tub I imagine. About to test the water coming out of the laundry for a smell!

Comment: @jsotola I'm not certain what you mean by the sewer stub comment

Comment: stub is just a short pipe for future expansion ... it should be capped properly ... there could be one in the wall ... if you don't have a laundry sink, it may be there for adding a sink

Comment: Ok that makes sense. If all else fails I'll remove the wall plate/open up the wall to see what's up there. BTW - I checked the water coming out the washer, smells perfectly fine

Comment: A good way to tell if there's a trap (functioning well enough to retain water) is lower a length of rope down the drain.  It should only go into the drain a few feet; certainly no further than the level of the finished floor.  Since you're not pushing the rope like you can a snake, it has only gravity to get down the drain; and you'll either find water in the trap (thus the rope will get soaking wet at the level of the trap water) or if there's no trap, it'll come out dry.

Comment: @JeffWheeler great tip thank you! I lowered a rope and about 19 inches past the floor the tip got very wet. Woohoo!

Comment: That's a good sign for the laundry drain, but it suggests the shop-vac'ing may have pulled loose some other drain which had been capped off before.  Finding it may be tough -- a **smoke test** could be helpful.  If you end up getting a plumber to help with this, keep in mind it may be an unusually tricky problem, and ask the plumber if they know how to perform a smoke test before deciding to call them out to your home.  If they don't know, that might not be the right plumber for your job.  :(

Comment: Oh, you said 19 inches *lower than the floor* is where the rope got wet, right?  What's underneath this laundry room; basement, crawl space?  Are you able to see any plumbing in that area?  If so, that could be helpful.  Try to get some pictures.

Comment: I have a crawlspace underneath the laundry room. Before I go searching for an uncapped drain, if this was the case wouldn't there be a sewer smell when there was no laundry done as well?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I determine if the sewer smell is from a lack of p-trap in the wall (ideally without removing drywall)?

It would be very unlikely for there not to be a trap; they are required by code. More likely you have a trap that is being siphoned dry, which can be caused by various problems including poor venting, clogged or partially clogged drain, poor design.

> Could the sewer smell come from another clog?

**YES**... well not really *coming from* another clog, but caused by a clog or partial clog.

> could I just put a p-trap outside of the wall attached to the plate to solve the smell?

**NO** you can't piggy-back traps. If there is a trap in the wall (and I would bet $5 that there is) you can't install an additional trap.

I would recommend that you ensure that all house drains are running free and clear (by whatever means necessary) and same with all vents. The fact that you merely wet-vacced the line and did not snake the drain line (

Comment: I couldn't get my 1/2" snake past a certain point on the drain line. When I wet-vacced and snaked the vent I got a ton of stuff out of there. Should I get a thin augur to snake the drain line? Do you have recommendation on how I should ensure the vent is free and clear?

Comment: Based on @jeffwheeler's comment above, there is a p-trap since lowering a rope into the drain caused the tip to get wet. So you're probably correct there is a p-trap. So I guess I have a partial clog that I need to get figured out.

Comment: The stuff down in the vent pipe is often debris that carried *up* into the vent and lodged there due to a drain line clog. Most definitely you should snake out the drain line.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with the smell as well.  In my case, I had to make sure that the washing machine's drain tube was not inserted too far down into the wall drain.  After reading a suggestion on the web, I retracted some of the tube back out of the drain.  The smell went away after the p-trap resealed itself with water.  The smell hasn't returned (3+ years ago).